# deployed docker app on AWS isn't reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask

I'm following test-driven Flask course made by Michael Herman.
I'm stuck at the stage where I deployed the containerized Flask app on
AWS. Everything seems to be configured correctly but when I try
to connect to the cluster using public_ip:5001/users I get "Unable to connect" screen.
[inbound port set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4LfG.png) [outbound port set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Nl0.png) [ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtDyM.png) [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjQoS.png)
[security group is selected correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgeKh.png)

Comment: For context, which service are you deploying to? This will usually be ECS, EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, etc., but it will help a lot to know which one.

My guess is that your security group is either misconfigured or not selected.

Comment: please see screenshots attached. It's EC2.

Comment: Okay, the other common issue is that the ports on your docker containers may not be correctly mapped to your host machine. Can you correctly access the service on port 5001 when SSH'd into your EC2 instance?

If not, you're probably looking at a port mapping issue.

Comment: @DrSatan1  Security group is selected and configured correctly. See screenshot.

Comment: @DrSatan1  I'm not connected to the instance via SSH. Didn't occur to me that it's a must.

Comment: It's not a must, and in a perfect world won't be necessary, but it's extremely useful when debugging connectivity issues. 

If the service works directly from the instance, you'll know for sure that you're looking at a security/connectivity issue as opposed to an actual issue with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do the build, make sure that your Docker client is pointed at the Docker machine on AWS. In other words, you may be doing the build locally rather than on the remote machine.

```sh
$ docker-machine env testdriven-prod
$ eval $(docker-machine env testdriven-prod)
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build
```

If that doesn't fix it, check the logs to ensure the build is working:

```sh
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml logs -f
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for taking time answering this. The build works like a charm locally. I can connect to the app on localhost:5001/users but when trying accessing it through AWS I get this in logs:  `nginx_1     | 2019/04/12 21:00:41 [emerg] 1#1: unknown "server" variable`

Comment: Please see here https://send.firefox.com/download/4fe7ba8fddf1c9f1/#7OdIEGRaytBsAJZ7ce017Q  I can see that it's trying to create databases but it receives shuts down request and hence fails to create "server" variable and exits returning 1. I'm not gathering much more than that though.

Comment: That link has expired.

Comment: Try now this link https://send.firefox.com/download/de529214216b71d1/#buJXSr658YIEuub5AfYb9g

Comment: Looks like the issue is with your Nginx config: `unknown "server" variable`

Comment: I'm learning configs from the course online.  https://send.firefox.com/download/fd46d20c2d1606b7/#4WelfzYFJozQCREywlT03A  this nginx error is driving me mad. It's been 4 days and still stuck on this. Embarrassing.